# how to fix JSON decoder issue when using REST in Python to connect to SharePoint & Read data

Tags: python, json, rest, sharepoint-2013

i am following this [Guide](http://tech.bool.se/using-python-to-request-data-from-sharepoint-via-rest/) in an effort to connect to a sharepoint site with python and grab some data using the REST api. however, i keep having trouble with the JSON decoder in order to read the data like it suggests in the guide.

I have followed the Guide to the letter and keep having the same issues. I tried to change the headers to `headers = {'content-type':'application/json'}`as it suggests on another question asked on here; but nothing has worked.

This is what i have so far much like the guide suggests:

```py
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

headers = {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}

response = requests.get("http://Sharepointsite/_api/web/", auth=HttpNtlmAuth('User','Pass'),headers=headers)

print(response.content)

print(response.json()["d"]["CustomMasterUrl"])
```

This is the error message that i get:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/MyProjects/ProductivityTracking/SharepointConnection/Sharepoint Integration.py", line 9, in <module>
    print (response.json()["d"]["CustomMasterUrl"])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)`

if you guys can point me in the right direction to start trouble shooting this, that would be awesome - i searched everywhere on stack and beyond.

Additional Info - the response content:

`b'\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"\r\n\t"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">\r\n<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">\r\n<head><meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" /><meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" /><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Fri, 11 Oct 2019 15:09:01 GMT" /><meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/_layouts/15/images/SharePointMetroAppTile.png" /><meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#0072C6" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=23" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" id="favicon" />\r\n<script type=\'text/javascript\'>\r\n// <![CDATA[\r\nvar url = window.location.href; var g_initUrl=\'\';\r\nvar hashSaverUrl = \'\';var keyName = \'MDSLoginAllowedUrl\';var idx = url.indexOf(\'&\' + keyName + \'=\');\r\nif (idx != -1) {\r\n    var idx2 = url.indexOf(\'&\', idx + 1);\r\n    if (idx2 == -1)\r\n        idx2 = url.length;\r\n    hashSaverUrl = url.substring(idx + keyName.length + 2, idx2);\r\n    hashSaverUrl = decodeURIComponent(hashSaverUrl);\r\n}\r\nif (!hashSaverUrl || hashSaverUrl == \'\') {\r\n    var g_MDSStartTime = new Date();\r\n    var g_MinimalDownload = true;var g_mdsReady=false;var isStartPlt1 = true;var startDate = g_MDSStartTime.valueOf().toString();\r\n    var skipOverlay=true;var startRenderComplete=false;var initContentComplete=false;\r\n    var hashParts=window.location.hash.substr(1).split(\'#\');var ch=hashParts[0];var localAnc=null; \r\n    for (var i=1;i<hashParts.length;i++){\r\n      var s=hashParts[i];\r\n      if (s.indexOf(\'=\') == -1) {\r\n        localAnc=s; \r\n        break;\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n\r\n    var requestUrlFull;\r\n    if (ch.length >= 2 && ch[0] === \'/\' && ch[1] === \'/\')\r\n    {\r\n        if (ch[2] !== \'/\')\r\n        {\r\n            g_initUrl = ch.substr(1);\r\n            requestUrlFull = window.location.hash.substr(2);\r\n        }\r\n    } else if (typeof(ch) != \'undefined\' && ch.length >= 1 && ch[0] === \'/\')\r\n    {\r\n        var loc = window.location.pathname;\r\n        var pos = loc.indexOf(\'/_layouts/15/start.aspx\');\r\n        var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);\r\n        var hPos = hash.indexOf(\'#\');\r\n        hPos = hPos >= 0 ? hPos : hash.length;\r\n        g_initUrl = loc.substr(0, pos) + ch;\r\n        requestUrlFull = g_initUrl + hash.substr(hPos);\r\n    }\r\n\r\n    if(g_initUrl){\r\n    var delim=ch.indexOf(\'?\')!=-1 ? \'&\' : \'?\';\r\n    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();\r\n    xhr.open(\'GET\',g_initUrl+delim+\'AjaxDelta=1&isStartPlt1=\' + startDate, true);\r\n    xhr.setRequestHeader(\'Pragma\', \'SharePointAjaxDelta=|SITES|SANDBOX:|SITES|SANDBOX|_CATALOGS|MASTERPAGE|SEATTLE.MASTER:2.15.0.0.0.15.0.5131.1000.0.FALSE.:en-US:en-US:RW\');\r\n    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){\r\n     if(xhr.readyState==4){\r\n      if(g_mdsReady){\r\n       asyncDeltaManager._navigate(requestUrlFull, localAnc);}\r\n      else\r\n      {g_mdsReady=true;}}};\r\n    xhr.send(null);}\r\n     else\r\n    {g_mdsReady=true;}\r\n}\r\n\r\n// ]]>\r\n</script>\r\n<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/Themable/corev15.css?rev=2bpHeX9U8DH09TB5zpJcsQ%3D%3D"/>\n<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js?rev=ZwTQYqYlNTyyuMWaLlhwSg%3D%3D"></script>\n<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=ideow4fpAMtT1LU3KRk4QdrhD1jlPBAePc9i8Ib6lUnFTPWZBlpLxAiBo8ORwOMMJgN20_t9vRkidn1TCfn8SlPTG2UqSNGHdiXmH-2qG7qawwjHGYQutflvf9Bq4OfLRdTYGOD6T8DyvDQ6rrD3oPhj_zf3sNcoJxJOKX0a2n2TdJGcEtmFj3kTppa6_7PE0&amp;t=ffffffffc60ca17c"></script>\n<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/blank.js?rev=ZaOXZEobVwykPO9g8hq%2F8A%3D%3D"></script>\n<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/start.js?rev=RJ1wZoVJ%2F7xfKjfBnjaWng%3D%3D"></script>\n<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("initstrings.js", "\\u002f_layouts\\u002f15\\u002f1033\\u002finitstrings.js?rev=S11vfGURQYVuACMEY0tLTg\\u00253D\\u00253D");</script>\n<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("strings.js", "\\u002f_layouts\\u002f15\\u002f1033\\u002fstrings.js?rev=0Q8SquDYHrVJnF3A1pfsSQ\\u00253D\\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("strings.js", "initstrings.js");</script>\n<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("sp.init.js", "\\u002f_layouts\\u002f15\\u002fsp.init.js?rev=jvJC3Kl5gbORaLtf7kxULQ\\u00253D\\u00253D");</script>\n<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("sp.res.resx", "\\u002f_layouts\\u002f15\\u002fScriptResx.ashx?culture=en\\u00252Dus\\u0026name=SP\\u00252ERes\\u0026rev=yNk\\u00252FhRzgBn40LJVP\\u00252BqfgdQ\\u00253D\\u00253D");</script>\n<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("sp.ui.dialog.js", "\\u002f_layouts\\u002f15\\u002fsp.ui.dialog.js?rev=3Oh2QbaaiXSb7ldu2zd6QQ\\u00253D\\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("sp.ui.dialog.js", "sp.init.js");RegisterSodDep("sp.ui.dialog.js", "sp.res.resx");</script>\n<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("core.js", "\\u002f_layouts\\u002f15\\u002fcore.js?rev=GpU7vxyOqzS0F9OfEX3CCw\\u00253D\\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("core.js", "strings.js");</script>\n<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("menu.js", "\\u002f_layouts\\u002f15\\u002fmenu.js?rev=cXv35JACAh0ZCqUwKU592w\\u00253D\\u00253D");</script>\n<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("mQuery.js", "\\u002f_layouts\\u002f15\\u002fmquery.js?rev=VYAJYBo5H8I3gVSL3MzD6A\\u00253D\\u00253D");</script>\n<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("callout.js", "\\u002f_layouts\\u002f15\\u002fcallout.js?rev=ryx2n4ePkYj1\\u00252FALmcsXZfA\\u00253D\\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("callout.js", "strings.js");RegisterSodDep("callout.js", "mQuery.js");RegisterSodDep("callout.js", "core.js");</script>\n<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("clienttemplates.js", "\\u002f_layouts\\u002f15\\u002fclienttemplates.js?rev=OJfMNjaofDqyBzPvjPo3XA\\u00253D\\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("clienttemplates.js", "initstrings.js");</script>\n<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("sharing.js", "\\u002f_layouts\\u002f15\\u002fsharing.js?rev=XxxHIxIIc8BsW9ikVc6dgA\\u00253D\\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("sharing.js", "strings.js");RegisterSodDep("sharing.js", "mQuery.js");RegisterSodDep("sharing.js", "clienttemplates.js");RegisterSodDep("sharing.js", "core.js");</script>\n<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("suitelinks.js", "\\u002f_layouts\\u002f15\\u002fsuitelinks.js?rev=REwVU5jSsadDdOZlCx4wpA\\u00253D\\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("suitelinks.js", "strings.js");RegisterSodDep("suitelinks.js", "core.js");</script>\n<link type="text/xml" rel="alternate" href="/sites/sandbox/_vti_bin/spdisco.aspx" /></head>\r\n<body>\r\n  <div id="imgPrefetch" style="display:none">\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n  <noscript><div class=\'noindex\'>You may be trying to access this site from a secured browser on the server. Please enable scripts and reload this page.</div></noscript>\r\n  \r\n  <form method="post" action="./start.aspx" id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) == &quot;function&quot;) return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();">\r\n<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTY1NDU2MTA1Mg9kFgJmD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIJDxYCHghvbnN1Ym1pdAVSaWYgKHR5cGVvZihfc3BGb3JtT25TdWJtaXRXcmFwcGVyKSA9PSAiZnVuY3Rpb24iKSByZXR1cm4gX3NwRm9ybU9uU3VibWl0V3JhcHBlcigpO2Rk82P14L36F04gkzB9Q1Z5k5kq+AtfmPqNYl/2Da94T8s=" />\r\n\r\n\r\n<script type="text/javascript">\r\n//<![CDATA[\r\nvar g_presenceEnabled = true;\nvar g_wsaEnabled = false;\nvar g_wsaQoSEnabled = false;\nvar g_wsaQoSDataPoints = [];\nvar g_wsaLCID = 1033;\nvar g_wsaListTemplateId = null;\nvar _fV4UI=true;var _spPageContextInfo = {webServerRelativeUrl: "\\u002fsites\\u002fsandbox", webAbsoluteUrl: "http:\\u002f\\u002fhemportal.hem.jmhuber.com\\u002fsites\\u002fsandbox", siteAbsoluteUrl: "http:\\u002f\\u002fhemportal.hem.jmhuber.com\\u002fsites\\u002fsandbox", serverRequestPath: "\\u002f_layouts\\u002f15\\u002fstart.aspx", layoutsUrl: "_layouts\\u002f15", webTitle: "", webTemplate: "", tenantAppVersion: "none", isAppWeb: false, Has2019Era: true, webLogoUrl: "_layouts\\u002f15\\u002fimages\\u002fsiteicon.png", webLanguage: 1033, currentLanguage: 1033, currentUICultureName: "en-US", currentCultureName: "en-US", clientServerTimeDelta: new Date("2019-09-11T15:09:01.6585779Z") - new Date(), siteClientTag: "0$$15.0.5131.1000", crossDomainPhotosEnabled:false, webUIVersion:15, webPermMasks:{High:0,Low:0}, pagePersonalizationScope:1, alertsEnabled:true, customMarkupInCalculatedFieldDisabled: true, siteServerRelativeUrl: "\\u002fsites\\u002fsandbox", allowSilverlightPrompt:\'True\'};var MSOWebPartPageFormName = \'aspnetForm\';//]]>\r\n</script>\r\n\r\n<script src="/_layouts/15/blank.js?rev=ZaOXZEobVwykPO9g8hq%2F8A%3D%3D" type="text/javascript"></script>\r\n<script type="text/javascript">\r\n//<![CDATA[\r\nif (typeof(DeferWebFormInitCallback) == \'function\') DeferWebFormInitCallback();//]]>\r\n</script>\r\n\r\n<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="A31D3FD9" />\r\n\t<script type="text/javascript"> var submitHook = function () { return false; }; theForm._spOldSubmit = theForm.submit; theForm.submit = function () { if (!submitHook()) { this._spOldSubmit(); } }; </script>\r\n\t<span id="DeltaSPWebPartManager"></span>\r\n\t\r\n\t<span id="DeltaDelegateControls"></span>\r\n<div id="TurnOnAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">\r\n\t<a id="linkTurnOnAcc" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(true);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById(\'linkTurnOffAcc\').focus();return false;">Turn on more accessible mode</a>\r\n</div>\r\n<div id="TurnOffAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">\r\n\t<a id="linkTurnOffAcc" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(false);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById(\'linkTurnOnAcc\').focus();return false;">Turn off more accessible mode</a>\r\n</div>\r\n<div class="s4-notdlg s4-skipribbonshortcut noindex">\r\n\t<a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById(&#39;startNavigation&#39;).focus();" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" accesskey="Y">Skip Ribbon Commands</a>\r\n</div>\r\n<div class="s4-notdlg noindex">\r\n\t<a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById(&#39;mainContent&#39;).focus();" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button">Skip to main content</a>\r\n</div>\r\n<div id="TurnOffAnimation" style="display:none;" class="s4-notdlg noindex">\r\n\t<a id="linkTurnOffAnimation" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="ToggleAnimationStatus();return false;">Turn off Animations</a>\r\n</div>\r\n<div id="TurnOnAnimation" style="display:none;" class="s4-notdlg noindex">\r\n\t<a id="linkTurnOnAnimation" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="ToggleAnimationStatus();return false;">Turn on Animations</a>\r\n</div>\r\n<a id="HiddenAnchor" href="javascript:;" style="display:none;"></a>\r\n<div id="suiteBar" class="ms-dialogHidden noindex">\r\n\t<div id="suiteBarLeft">\r\n\t\t<div class="ms-table ms-fullWidth">\r\n\t\t\t<div class="ms-tableRow">\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignMiddle">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t<div id="DeltaSuiteLinks" class="ms-core-deltaSuiteLinks">\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t</div>\r\n\t<div id="suiteBarRight">\r\n\t\t<div id="DeltaSuiteBarRight" class="ms-core-deltaSuiteBarRight">\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n\t</div>\r\n</div>\r\n\t\t<div id="ms-hcTest"></div>\r\n\t\t<div id="s4-ribbonrow">\r\n\t\t<div id="globalNavBox" class="noindex">\r\n<div id="ribbonBox">\r\n\t<div id="s4-ribboncont">\r\n\t\t<div id="DeltaSPRibbon">\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n\t</div>\r\n\t<span id="DeltaSPNavigation"></span>\r\n</div>\r\n<div id="DeltaWebPartAdderUpdatePanelContainer" class="ms-core-webpartadder">\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t<div id="s4-workspace" class="ms-core-overlay">\r\n\t\t<div id="s4-bodyContainer">\r\n\t\t<div id="s4-titlerow"\r\n\t\t\tclass="ms-dialogHidden s4-titlerowhidetitle">\r\n\t\t<div id="titleAreaBox"\r\n\t\t\tclass="ms-noList ms-table ms-core-tableNoSpace">\r\n\t\t<div id="titleAreaRow"\r\n\t\t\tclass="ms-tableRow">\r\n<div id="siteIcon" class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">\r\n\t<div id="DeltaSiteLogo">\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n\t\t\t<div class="ms-breadcrumb-box ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">\r\n\t\t\t\t<div\r\n\t\t\t\t\tclass="ms-breadcrumb-top">\r\n<div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox" style="display:none;">\r\n<span id="DeltaBreadcrumbDropdown"></span>\r\n</div>\r\n<div id="DeltaTopNavigation" class="ms-displayInline ms-core-navigation" role="navigation">\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n<h1 id="pageTitle" class="ms-core-pageTitle">\r\n  <span id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea"></span>\r\n  <div id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageDescription" class="ms-displayInlineBlock ms-normalWrap">\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n</h1>\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t<div class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">\r\n<div id="DeltaPlaceHolderSearchArea" class="ms-mpSearchBox ms-floatRight">\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t<div id="contentRow">\r\n<div id="sideNavBox"\r\n\t class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList">\r\n  <div id="DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar" class="ms-core-navigation" role="navigation">\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div id="contentBox"\r\n aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">\r\n  <div id="notificationArea" class="ms-notif-box"></div>\r\n\t<div id="DeltaPageStatusBar">\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n\t<div id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain">\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div id="DeltaFormDigest">\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\r\n\r\n<script type="text/javascript">\r\n//<![CDATA[\r\n\r\nvar filesExist = true;\r\nif (typeof(initJsLoaded) === \'undefined\') { filesExist = false; }\r\nelse if (typeof(Sys) === \'undefined\') { filesExist = false; }\r\nelse if (typeof(Sys.WebForms) === \'undefined\') { filesExist = false; }\r\nelse if (typeof(startJsLoaded) === \'undefined\') { filesExist = false; }\r\nvar sessionStorageEnabled = window.sessionStorage != null;\r\nif (!filesExist) {\r\n if (!sessionStorageEnabled || window.sessionStorage[\'spFilesExist\'] === \'false\'){\r\n  if (\'undefined\' != typeof(g_initUrl) && null != g_initUrl && \'\' != g_initUrl)\r\n  {\r\n   try\r\n   {\r\n    if (sessionStorageEnabled) \r\n    {\r\n     window.sessionStorage[\'spFilesExist\'] = \'true\';\r\n    }\r\n   }\r\n   catch (e) {}\r\n   var tempAnchor = document.createElement(\'a\');\r\n   tempAnchor.href = g_initUrl;\r\n   var redir = tempAnchor.href;\r\n   tempAnchor = null;\r\n   window.location.href=redir;\r\n  }\r\n }else{\r\n  try\r\n  {\r\n   window.sessionStorage[\'spFilesExist\'] = \'false\';\r\n   window.location.reload(true);\r\n  }\r\n  catch (e) {}\r\n }\r\n} else {\r\n if (sessionStorageEnabled)\r\n {\r\n  window.sessionStorage[\'spFilesExist\'] = \'true\';\r\n }\r\n}\r\nvar workingOnIt = \'Working on it...\';var _spFullDownloadList = [\'closeconnection\', \'download\', \'signout\', \'xlviewer\', \'wordviewer\', \'wordeditor\', \'powerpoint\', \'powerpointframe\', \'onenote\', \'visiowebaccess\', \'storefront\', \'wopiframe\', \'appredirect\', \'wfstart\'];\nif (\'undefined\' != typeof(AsyncDeltaManager$onError)) window.onerror = AsyncDeltaManager$onError;\nvar _fV4UI = true;var origMP = \'|SITES|SANDBOX:|SITES|SANDBOX|_CATALOGS|MASTERPAGE|SEATTLE.MASTER:2.15.0.0.0.15.0.5131.1000.0.FALSE.:en-US:en-US:RW\';var phMain = \'DeltaPlaceHolderMain\';var g_AjaxDeltaList = [{id:\'DeltaPlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead\', container:false},{id:\'DeltaSPWebPartManager\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaDelegateControls\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaSuiteLinks\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaSuiteBarRight\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaSPRibbon\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaSPNavigation\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaWebPartAdderUpdatePanelContainer\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaSiteLogo\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaBreadcrumbDropdown\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaTopNavigation\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaPlaceHolderPageDescription\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaPlaceHolderSearchArea\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaPageStatusBar\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaPlaceHolderMain\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaFormDigest\', container:true},{id:\'DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent\', container:true}];\n\r\nfunction submitHook() {{return asyncDeltaManager._onFormSubmit();}}\r\nfunction _startOnSubmitStatement() {{return asyncDeltaManager._doSubmitStatements();}}\r\nfunction WebForm_OnSubmit() {{ return asyncDeltaManager._doSubmitStatements(); }}\r\n\r\nif (typeof(hashSaverUrl) != \'undefined\' && hashSaverUrl && hashSaverUrl != \'\') {\r\n    if ( (function(u, d) {\r\n            var idxDb = u.indexOf(\'//\');\r\n            if (-1 != idxDb) {\r\n                var idxDe = u.indexOf(\'/\', idxDb+2);\r\n                if  (-1 == idxDe) idxDe = u.length;\r\n                var D = u.substring(idxDb+2, idxDe);\r\n                if (d.toUpperCase() != D.toUpperCase()) return true;\r\n            }\r\n            return false;\r\n        }) (hashSaverUrl, document.location.host)) { hashSaverUrl = \'/\';}\r\n    window.location.replace(STSPageUrlValidation(hashSaverUrl));\r\n}\r\nvar g_clientIdDeltaPlaceHolderMain = "DeltaPlaceHolderMain";\r\nvar g_clientIdDeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea = "DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea";\r\nvar g_clientIdDeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent = "DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent";\r\n//]]>\r\n</script>\r\n</form>\r\n\t<span id="DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent"></span>\r\n\t<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[ \n\r\n\r\n\t\tvar g_Workspace = "s4-workspace";\r\n\t// ]]>\r\n</script>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'`

Comment: This output is not JSON. It's a full HTML-page. You need to modify your request to actually deliver JSON. Whatever that entails depends on the server (sharepoint in this instance).

Comment: any ideas on a resource to help me with that?

Comment: sharepoint documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check the steps below.

1.Install requests.

```
pip install requests
```

2.Install requests_ntlm.

```
pip install requests_ntlm
```

3.Make the username(domain\username) and password are right, and run the code as below.

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

headers = {'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'}
r = requests.get("http://sp2013/sites/team/_api/web", auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\admin', 'password'), headers=headers)

print(r.json()["d"]["CustomMasterUrl"])
```

[image]

Comment: I re checked all of this and still running to the same error message. my username and password are correct and it is passing the authentication process but it gets stuck on the decoder with JSON. i can call `r.content` but i cant decode it

Comment: Access the REST API in browser directly and check the results data.